# How do I maintain cookies across many WWW::Mechanize runs?

Tags: perl, cookies, mechanize

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use strict;
my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new(cookie_jar => {ignore_discard => 0});
$agent->add_header('User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0');
$agent->get($url);
my $content = $agent->content;
```

Comment: What sorts of cookies are you trying to create, and why? Is there some reason you can't use or copy the cookies that are set by the target website?

Comment: yes that website asking for cookies because of that  i am not able to get content

Answer (score 2):

The `cookie_jar` attribute expects a [HTTP::Cookies](http://p3rl.org/HTTP%3a%3aCookies) object.

```
WWW::Mechanize->new(
    cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies->new(
        file => 'lwp_cookies.dat',
        autosave => 1,
    )
)
```

Your mistake was to declare a plain hashref, this means a temporary in-memory cookie store that is destroyed after Mechanize ends.

Comment: Thank u. daxim but how can i use the same cookie for another url

Comment: Simply copy a cookie and modify the path and domain. `$agent->cookie_jar->scan(sub { my @cookie = @_; if ($cookie[3] eq '/' and $cookie[4] eq 'www.example.net') { @cookie[3,4] = ('/fnord', 'www.example.com'); $agent->cookie_jar->set_cookie(@cookie); });`